# literal and eval is not working on codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to make a video path work on literal by getting the eval from the code behind. But I couldn't get it to work. This is what I've done so far:

On My Code Behind:

```
    public string GetVideoLink(string holdingval)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        holdingval = "";
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM 
            discussion_table WHERE file_type='video' && 
            unique_id=@unique_id", con))
            {
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unique_id", u.client_id);
                using (MySqlDataAdapter ad = new MySqlDataAdapter(com))
                {
                    dt.Clear();
                    ad.Fill(dt);
                    discussion_video_grid.DataSource = dt;
                    discussion_video_grid.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (DataRow rows in dt.Rows)
        {
            string locreader = rows.Field<string>("discussion_material_location");
            string locpath = "<video class=video_class Controls><Source src=" + locreader + " type=video/mp4></video>";
            holdingval = locpath;
        }

        return holdingval;
    }
```

On my html:

```
   <asp:Literal ID="videoshow" runat="server" Text='<%# 
   GetVideoLink(Eval(holdingval)) %> ' ></asp:Literal>
```

Comment: "Not working" is not a useful description of the problem. Be more accurate. Is there an error? Is the output different than expected? What IS expected? Are there any rows coming back from the database at all?

Comment: Why just not assigning literal text at the end of GetVideoLink method like videoshow.Text = holdingval;

Comment: I'm having an error: The name 'holdingval' does not exist in the current context. Yes I can accomplish what I'm trying to do on just putting the eval on Text='' but there's function that I'll be doing that requires closing the file path.

Comment: 1. You have one literal control to hold all values from a table? Or is the literal inside a data control? 2. You are looping through all rows of a table but you are doing nothing with the values inside the loop. You leave the loop and return... the last value only? 3. If you call a function in code behind, i don't think you need Eval, just return the value.

Comment: Thank you so much for your replies but the problem is already been resolved.